# Very slow subquery in MySQL with GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, group-by, subquery

I've got this SQL:

```
SELECT COUNT( d.id ) AS sum, d.user_agent
FROM debug AS d
WHERE d.id IN (
    SELECT MAX(d2.id)
    FROM debug AS d2
    GROUP BY d2.user_id
)
GROUP BY d.user_agent
```

I want to get the amounts of similar useragents but only the useragents of the last entry of each user.

=> COUNT(d.id)

=> GROUP BY d2.user_id

I tried both SQLs separated and wrote the response of the subquery plain in the other query. The execution time was far under a second. 
Both together about 25 seconds.

My table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `debug` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `event` varchar(127) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_agent` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `parameters` varchar(5000) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `user_agent` (`user_agent`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

SQL-Fiddle:
[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5604eb/1)

Any ideas how I can optimize it?

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: I created a sqlfiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this any better?

```
SELECT x.user_agent
     , COUNT(*) total
  FROM debug x
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT user_id
            , MAX(id) max_id
         FROM debug 
        GROUP
           BY user_id
     ) y
    ON y.user_id = x.user_id
   AND y.max_id = x.id
 GROUP BY user_agent;
```

Comment: Thanks! 0.0039 Seconds. But why is this one faster? Because you used an alias for the subquery?

Comment: @Stefan I understand that IN() is not particularly well optimized in MySQL (although it depends a little on exactly which version you're using). In general, an uncorellated subquery (such as the example above) performs as well as or better than anything else.

Comment: So in future I try to take a JOIN instead of a subquery. Thank you :)